# Connection refused cuand hago peticion $http Post con angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Tengo una aplicacion usando Angular JS. Al momento de hacer una petición al backend que lo tengo en PHP. Me arroja el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error solo aparece cuando uso la aplicación desde otro dispositivo que no es el servidor.

Para hacer la peticion, ocupo el siguiente metodo:

```js
   utils.getHttp = function (getAuth, getUrl, getData){ // Boleano, si necesita autorizacion, URL de la peticion, y un objeto con los datos.
return $http({
  method: 'POST',
  skipAuthorization: getAuth,
  url: getUrl,
  data: getData,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  //console.log(response);
    if ('error' in response.data) {
    return $q.reject(response);
  }
  return response;
}).catch(function errorCallback(response) {
  console.error(response);
  return $q.reject(response.data);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La url dice `localhost`, tendrías que cambiar eso por la dirección ip pública o de la intranet si fuera el caso.

Solo podes acceder a localhost desde el servidor mismo.